# jqm Stop tap events queuing when busy

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am creating an app using jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap.

I "delegate" a button on "tap" to perform some heavy processing and display a loading spinner.  If users continue to tap on my app, the taps get queued up and fall through to be processed by the app after the heavy processing completes - and end up clicking on unwanted stuff.

**How can I prevent this?**

(From what I understand, stopImmediatePropagation doesn't help as these are new user events.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it took me a while to figure it out... you have to return FALSE from the delegate function for parent elements to ignore the event.  The return false line below fixes my issue:

```
$(document).delegate("#finish", "tap", onFinish);

var onFinish = function() {
    $.mobile.loadingMessage = "Finishing...";
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

    setTimeout(function(){  
        HEAVYPROCESSING();
        $.mobile.changePage($("#choosearticle"));
        }, 50);

    return false; // important - stops the two click fall through problem!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To inactive taps on the whole page you could overlay the whole page with a transparent div. Although it might be considered a borderline hack - this would actually use minimal js and css!

The caveat is that it would not give any visual indicator that the page is inactivated.

To do that one could, use a semitransparent gray for the overlay or, as I've done below, show a loading message.

First off, a small CSS discussion:

To make the div cover the whole page set width and height 100%. To position it correctly, use position:absolute and for the transparent background use an rgba background-color property (see below). You should also declare a z-index (can be increased if needed) to ensure that it goes on top of everything else and remove tap-callout using the -webkit-tap-highlight-color property. Set display to none and then show it during your heavy lifting.

I made a [jsfiddle which hopefully clears things up](http://jsfiddle.net/RegHV/).

Here I've made div with an id of "inactivator" which features the properties discussed above.
I've also made a button with an id of "inactivate" to which I've delegated jQuery's show function.
I also took the liberty to add jQuery Mobile's default loading message to show simultaneously just to give a visual indicator of the app thinking (so it's not mistaken for lag).

Here I've added a timeout function so that the loading message and "inactivator" hides after 5 second. Obviously in your case the same code should instead be fired upon completion of your "heavy processing" rather than after five seconds.

(New, additional answer since I didn't understand the question correctly but the old answer still might be helpful to other people.)

Comment: your comprehensive answer is appreciated - i will respond when i have a worthy response!

Comment: If you have any questions, I'll be glad to clarify

Comment: this was the best answer I didn't write ;)   i loved the way the effect looked, and ended up using it anyway with transparency + a slight tint of blue.  What a look!  It's a shame it didn't prevent the 'click fall through effect'.. Thx for the good answer tho.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is inactivating the button at the start of your javascript function and then reactivating it when it's suitable:

```
$('#YourButton').addClass('ui-disabled');
```

At the end of your function (or whenever you'd want it active again:

```
$('#YourButton').removeClass('ui-disabled');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Will become a very messy solution for me as it's a complex, programatically generated jqm list behind there.  Surely there's a simple way to catch and discard these unwanted clicks without specifically referring to all the possible elements that could mistakenly be clicked on?

Comment: So it's the whole page you want to disable clicks on while your app is thinking?

Comment: Yes, will post as new answer in a few hours